# Visual studio 2010 show Errors when building silverlight application in release mode

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

I have a Silverlight 4 project which is running good but only if I build/run in debug mode of VS2010.
If I try to build in release mode am getting multiple errors like .."the type or namespace name 'Expander' could not be found", am I missing anything here ?

Comment: maybe you have treat warnings as errors on in release mode only?

Comment: Can you post your csproj file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toolkits that you use should all be included while publishing your project.

Select the toolkit and then in the 'Properties' tab, there is a 'Copy to Output Directory' option, select 'Copy Always'.

I hope that solves your problem!